# List all txt records for a doman

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, domain, txt-record

How can I list all the txt records for a domain? All online tools i checked only list the firt one they find and the nslookup the same. I wish to do this on a windows machine.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean all the TXT records associated with example.com or all the TXT records for all the childs of the example.com domain?

All the TXT records for example.com should be returned when you query them with dig. However, requesting the TXT records for all childs of the example.com domain is not possible unless you can do an AXFR transfer of the entire zone.

Comment: There is an exception to this - if the nameserver is doing DNSSEC, configured to use `NSEC` records (and not `NSEC3`), then the zone is easily walkable, as discussed [here](https://www.farsightsecurity.com/2017/09/01/stsauver-zone-walking/). There are various tools out there to facilitate walking of domains using `NSEC` records.

Answer (score 3):

As Tom said, you can't search all hosts in a domain without a zone transfer, which is usually forbidden.

In Windows (without `dig`): To get all records for a given host name, you can use

```
nslookup -q=TXT <hostname>
```